# Freezes Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome

I had 19.04 version of Ubuntu as my first Linux distribution.
I changed it on 18.04(because it is LTS).
19.04 was OK for sure. But 18.04 is freezing so much, when I alt-tab programs or just using someone.

What could it be? How can I fix that?
What information should I share?

`ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`:

result:
`ls: cannot access '/home/andrew/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory`

`ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`:

result:

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb  3 19:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Feb  3 19:24 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb  3 19:24 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb  3 19:24 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

`free -h`
result:

```
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        4.6G        458M        518M        2.7G        2.3G
Swap:          2.0G        259M        1.7G
```

`sysctl vm.swappiness` result:

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

Maybe it is normal, that it laggs when I have opened:
    -Chrome
    -Intellij Idea
    -Telegram Desktop
    sometimes more:
    -pg4Admin
    -Postman
    -pdf files

```
 *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.2.3
       date: 05/15/2019
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 15MiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 3d
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM [empty]
          physical id: 0
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: HMA81GS6AFR8N-UH
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 1
          serial: 2B89D03D
          slot: DIMM B
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 41
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 42
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 43
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 6MiB
       capacity: 6MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 21
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d232c000-d232ffff
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: <code>grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*</code>:]

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Let me know when you've got that info. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema updated.

Comment: That looks normal. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: @heynnema added free -h, but when i do second command, I`ve got too big list of information

Comment: Thanks for the info. You entered the second command incorrectly, as you added a trailing ".". The data itself looks fine. Let me put together a quick answer for the next step... give me a couple of minutes... Report back.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: what do you mean status?

Comment: I'm asking if your computer is running OK now, and if my answer helped at all.

Comment: @heynnema As you remember, we didnt find a problem, why it is lagging.
Anyway it is running OK, if I dont use some programms like Postman, and just dont use more than 4-5 programs in one time

Comment: To see if you have a memory/swap restraint, use the `free -h` command in terminal, or use the `System Monitor` app, to view memory/swap use. That might explain any lagging.

Comment: @heynnema I`ve added screen(last) of the result of this command

Comment: Added screen. And ofcourse there were helpful and useful answers from you :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**fsck**

Let's check your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in "Try Ubuntu" mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**memtest**

Let's run a memory test...

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

**Update #1:**

Your `DELL Inspiron P75F` has BIOS version 1.2.3 which is current.

**Update #2:**

Recent `free -h` commands indicate that memory is full. Add memory. Make sure you do it in matched pairs... so if you've got one 8G DIMM now, add a matching 8G DIMM. <strike>If you've got two 4G DIMMS now, then replace them with two 8G DIMMs.</strike> You can use `sudo lshw -C memory` to see how your memory is configured now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105775/discussion-between-heynnema-and-andrew-korzhov).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105841/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-freezes-ubuntu-18-04).

Comment: Correct me, if I understood you wrong, you mean I have to add to my PC 1 more RAM with 8GB? Or it is something virtual?

Comment: @AndrewKorzhov  Yes, I'm recommending that you add more RAM... but lets look at just a couple more things real quick... Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory`, and `grep -i fpdma /var/log/syslog*` and `grep -i ncq /var/log/syslog*` and `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*` and if the output is large, use paste.ubuntu.com... and then we'll talk some more...

Comment: @heynnema First command added to question. Second shows me nothing. And 3-4 will be added as screens too now.

Comment: @AndrewKorzhov thanks for the info... however, the `sudo lshw -C memory` is missing the most important parts... can you please rerun the command, only this time copy the output to the clipboard, edit your question, paste in the text, select the pasted text, then click the `{}` icon to format it. Thanks.

Comment: @heynnema yes, sure. You can see that above screenshots

Comment: @AndrewKorzhov No, the screenshot doesn't cover the entire output for that command, and it's missing the most important part. Best to repeat the command, copy the output to the clipboard, edit your answer, paste the clipboard, select the pasted text, then click the `{}` icon to format it. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema but look, I have already added that, above(I mean on top of all screenshots) :)

Comment: @AndrewKorzhov Oh, so sorry! I missed it way up there! Usually updates go at the end. Anyway, I updated my `Update #2` with the correct info for you, if you ever decide to upgrade memory. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this with you definitely need more ram, especially with the programs you are running. If you are unwilling or unable to buy more ram the below MIGHT help.

I had some issues with my installation freezing as well, couple of things that might help.

Increase your swap file size, general rule of thumb is the swap file should be at least 1X the ram, better if you can afford 1.5X the ram.

The other thing you can do is turn down your swappiness so it is less apt to swap to the file. In conjunction with this it is probably a good idea to increase your ram as well if you can.

Comment: You can't generalize swap sizes without doing some investigation work first. And you certainly shouldn't recommend vm.swappiness changes unless you understand the impact on RAM vs swap. Sorry.

Comment: I'm speaking from my experience dealing with a very similar issue and the steps I took to resolving that issue. My answer is more of a follow up to what you have already stated in your answer. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I saw the image of the disks and i didnt see the swap partition. 
Im new to this of linux, but when i read how to install linux, they suggested me to make a partition aproximately of the size of the ram that u have in the system to make the things "flush".
I checked the command that you putted in the console to see if my swap appear and there it is.

I have 4GB of ram, but i made a special partition of 8GB of ram as Swap.

I also saw that you have 8gb of ram, and i consider that is more than enough to run Ubuntu

Im running Lubuntu 18.04 and i didnt have problems with freezing, and i have the half of ram that you have.

About the used ram, i have readen that the system uses almost all ram as cache, and when is neccesary it frees the ram for the programs.

You have a lot of space on your disk and you linux partition, so there is not the problem.

I can suggest you, only to assure that is right, to check the speed of reading of you disk. I only have freezing when my disk is writing a lot, so maybe the problem is there.

Another suggestion could be to make more than one partition when you install linux. I saw that ussualy the people make three partitions:

"/"

"/home"

"Swap"

I think that the "/" and "/home" separated could be for format the SO and dont lost your things in the process(i prefer copy the files on windows and format the three partitions, but that is my way)

I hope that some of the things that i posted could help you. 
Im sorry if my english isnt look very good, im not english native.